# Wikipedia API - get random page(s) using rest api

Tags: wikipedia, mediawiki

I try to get a random page in Wikipedia using their rest api. I do as suggested in https://stackoverflow.com/a/56518662 :

```
curl -X GET "https://en.wikipedia.org/api/rest_v1/page/random/summary"
```

but nothing is returned. Perhaps, it's because there is a redirect. What should I do? The answer is perhaps obvious if we read the curl documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the command line:

```
curl -sL "https://en.wikipedia.org/api/rest_v1/page/random/summary" | jq
```

Using the Python programming language:

```
import requests
page = requests.get("https://en.wikipedia.org/api/rest_v1/page/random/summary").json()
```

Comment: It's the same answer that I provided, but you added the silent option -s and piped the result to a json processor. Anyway, I will accept yours, because the output is way nicer at the command line.

Answer (score 1):

Simply add the -L option and, usually,  you don't need the -X GET option, because it's the default:

```
curl -L "https://en.wikipedia.org/api/rest_v1/page/random/summary"
```

or simply use wget:

```
wget "https://en.wikipedia.org/api/rest_v1/page/random/summary" -O outputfile
```